# Deploying a PHP/MySQL Application in Cloud (AWS)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, load-balancing

How to deploy an application (in this case a PHP and MySQL based) in a multiple server environment. To be specific, the application is supposed to be deployed as per below mentioned configuration.

- MySQL on Amazon RDS
- Application (PHP) on 2 EC2 instances

MySQL part is obvious however I need some clarity on how to deploy the application on 2 servers. I understand that I probably need to setup the application on both EC2 instances and somehow AWS elastic load balancing will automatically balance the load.

Are there any specific configuration/code changes I need to make in the application to work in such an environment? In my case the application would be based on either Cake or Yii. Are they cloud ready by default? If not, what changes, if any, that are needed.

Essentially, I am looking for a guide or instructions which clarifies all such doubts and helps me deploy the application as per above mentioned configuration.

Comment: Your main thing will be session handling - if servers are used on a round-robin basis, sessions can no longer be stored locally on the web server. The common approach is to use the database for session storage instead. Of course, if you want to do testing, just acquire the necessary cloud servers now, and see how it works? You could write a demo app in a few hours that uses sessions and communicates with the database.

Comment: (Discursive questions like this, incidentally, are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It is likely to close as too broad or a request for third party resources. I recommend reading the help centre, it is unusually good).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) when I deploy my Yii application into multiple ec2 instances.

I think the following article would help :

- Deploy PHP Websites Using Capistrano (and Git) | Fred Wu's Blog
  http://fredwu.me/post/720733257/deploy-php-websites-using-capistrano-and-git

Then, following would help, when you create your first config file of Capistrano for Yii.

- deploy.rb
  https://gist.github.com/kix/3913165

Comment: Thanks but Capistrano seems to be more like a workflow tool for deployment and for automating it. What I am interested in is understanding how the application would work in multiple service environment. For example, do I just install the app on all required servers and leave the rest to AWS for load balancing?

Comment: Well, let me be clear. What you'd like to know is "Wheather you need to deploy app to ELB"? If so, the answer is No. Neither impossible. I think you can know more about ELB by just googling ELB